# Async Function returns a Pending Promise

Tags: asynchronous

I'm currently trying to return a value from my async function but getting returned a pending Promise. Here is my code below:

```
let checker = async(url) => {
   const result = await axios(url)
      .then(({ data }) => {
         if (data.status === "pending") {
            return true;
         } else {
            return false;
         }
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
   return result;
}

let n = 1;
while (n < 3) {
   let result = checker(url);
   if (result === true){
      //do some stuff 
   };
   n++;
}
```

I also tried returning the result in Promise.resolve(result) but still got a pending Promise. Can someone help me fix this?

Comment: Because checker itself is ashnc, it will also return a promise. Maybe show some of your code when you're calling the checker function

Comment: I see. I updated the code above to show how the checker function is being used.

Comment: Ah i figured it out. In my while loop I can just invoke checker(url).then((result) => //do stuff with the result). Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

I can first return a Promise.resolve(result) in my checker function.

Then, I can use the result of the checker by invoking it in my while loop and accessing it after the .then.

```
while (n < 3) {
   checker(url)
      .then((result) =>
         //use result
      )
   n++;
}
```